# Table indexes are messed up when trying to assign values to fields from textboxes

Tags: sql-server, indexing

There's was a table with 4 columns. Everything was fine, but then I decided to add one more column to the table. After adding it and trying to save the table schema the Visual Studio 2010 said that it can't save the table unless I go to **Tools>Option>Table and Database Designers** and un-check **Prevent saving changes that require table recreation**. After doing so I was able to save the updated table schema, but the column indexes got messed up some how. If you try to edit or add data to the table through the table designer everything looks fine, but since my application has an **"Add"** button which when clicked tries to validate and assign the text-box values(there's 4 text-boxes, 5 table columns because one is for primary key) to the indexes of a new row, the values get placed into incorrect fields. I tried to delete the table and recreate it manually this time with correct columns but the indexes are still messed up. How can I fix the indexes for good?

Comment: Can you post the SQL script that is created when you re-create your table?  Also, a code snippet of your save code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you aren't accessing them by name, but by number (e.g. index) and the addition of the new field is throwing off the numbers of the old ones.

E.g.

```
Index   FieldName
1       FirstName
2       LastName
```

Now if you update and include middle initial you'll get

```
Index   FieldName
1       FirstName
2       MiddleName
3       LastName
```

But it's actually hard to tell without some code example